# Gif does not display in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, gif

It loads every other gifs, but not this particular one. It displays a box instead. If I right click on the file and go to properties, the file type = Not available.

But the gif opens in image editors. It works well with Opera. Trying to specify alpha does not resolve.

EDIT: You can download the file here: http://www.4shared.com/photo/uP0NtD6o/one.html

What are my options? Thanks.

--------- Ignore below as google page modifies the existing gif ------------

Alternatively I tried uploading the gif to google pages, but this time I can see the image in IE, not sure if google engine is modifying the gif.

[link to google test page](https://sites.google.com/site/testonegif/home)

```
<IMG height=1 src="https://sites.google.com/site/testonegif/home/one.gif?height=1&amp;width=100" width=100 border=0>
```

Comment: what version(s) of IE are affected?

Comment: @Badr Hari : It was google's generated markup and does not impact the issue above.

Comment: I tested the exact code you gave and it renders same in every browser for me. Even in IE6/7/8

Comment: @Badr Hari: Kindly read the issue above, the link (google test page) works for me too. The best way to test is to save the gif on your local machine and try open it from your browser or create a simple html  <IMG height=1 src="one.gif" width=100 border=0> and open it.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that this is not a gif file (I downloaded it and tried it locally), 
it is a jpeg file with a gif extension. I don't know why it work on google server, but that is the reason...

Make a new **gif** file and try again.

EDIT: The new file you uploaded is a BMP file with GIF extension... what program are you using to make this gif file?!

Comment: Google are running a script that returns a resource with `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. A resource's filename is immaterial to its media type on the web, but still, it's a bit perverse to be serving a JPEG from a URL with a `.gif` at the end of the filename...

Comment: Normally IE (11) would detect this, and display it correctly. But if the HTTP-header X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff is set (for security reasons), then IE will not do so (by design).

Answer (score 0):

If the animated gif image is not animating in IE. Here is the solution I find which makes the gif animating in IE also. Please visit the [link](http://www.codeinsects.com/how-to-show-animated-loading-gif-image-in-internet-explorer-using-javascript.html) for complete information.